# Xilinx FSBL documentation

Tags: xilinx

May be anyone knows where to find any documentation concerning FSBL. I'm trying to rewrite existing default first step boot loader. I have done few attempts to understand how it works (in debug mode), but debug mode always stops after
`/*
  * Register the Exception handlers
  */
  RegisterHandlers();`

The device reboots, and i still have no idea why.

I'm using xilinx sdk 2014.1, the device connected with xilix platform cable usb II.

Comment: What is FSBL? Are these the MicroBlaze links?

Comment: FSBL- first step boot loader. Its kinda  l2 bios.

Comment: Maybe ps7_init() didnt setup DDR correctly? ps7_init() comes fro the hw export, there is also a tcl version ps7_init.tcl, try that one and see wether you can access your DDR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passed almost 3 years, but now we have access to the XILINX FSBL [documentation](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/FSBL)

Comment: The link seems to be broken, [here is the FSBL wiki page for Zynq Ultrascale+](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18842019/Zynq+UltraScale+FSBL)